# Rendered animation brightness shifted in some players but not others

Tags: rendering, animation

My rendered animation output's brightness is way too high in some players but not Windows 10's default player and Blender's play rendered animation. **I think either the codec setting is wrong or Blender's output format is bugged?**

Firefox, which specifically stated it supports MP4 container with H.264 codec, says the file is **corrupted** when I tried playing the file in it.

<s>**Output:**</s>

- **All extensions**
- 24 fps

**Encoding:**

- Tested formats: **All codecs**
- Others are default

### Apparently, AVI RAW is the only format that works.

[image]

**Notice the background color.** They are marked.

I have experienced similar problem with other render softwares on my other PC. Is this a universal thing?

By request, here is the final frame image I'm rendering: (The sample is low, I know)

[image]

The background color is #111111. It is precisely correct.

Comment: Looks more like a (player) **gamma issue**, For comparison you could try to render an image sequence instead and encode it afterwards.

Comment: @poor Why is that though. Is that because the encoding is errored?

Comment: I think it's caused by the player. I'd suggest check your vlc settings first. Could you please add a rendered image to the question?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on a video editing forum as well since it's pretty specific to video formats. The only immediate things that comes to mind to ask are - are you first rendering image sequences in either OpenEXR or Radiance HDR formats by any chance? Also what is your color depth?

Comment: @Mentalist I'm really not sure if it's a video encoder problem or Blender's, but it's made in Blender. I might as well ask it here :/

Comment: @poor I've edited my question

Comment: @poor Nope, rendering from sequence is still problematic

Comment: I expect the issue you are seeing is an artefact of colour management, while blender uses a colour profile in it's image generation - I'm not sure if it embeds the info into a video file, not all software will read it or will use their own default settings. As @poor suggests it may only be the gamma setting, try [adjusting the gamma](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/cm_and_exposure.html#settings)

Comment: @sambler Thanks for you reply, I don't think it's a gamma thing, the internal playback is perfectly fine, just externally, some players have problem playing it. But the weird thing is, all the format failed except for **AVI RAW**

Comment: More to the point is what gamma setting each player uses and does any of them read the gamma setting in the video? If one reads the gamma adjustment and others don't then adjusting the gamma to match will allow the others to get the same colour. Of note is that every screen that other people use to watch the video will look different due to custom brightnes/contrast settings and variations between monitors, I have an asus and a samsung monitor side by side, each shows a slightly different colour, you shouldn't get too fixated on this.

Comment: @sambler OK, I had an experience using another video editing software and the brightness turned up too. But if I turned the gamma down, blender and other player will see the darker version and the others will see the "normal" version. The problem will just shift?

Comment: @sambler Also, it doesn't look like a gamma shift, more like a brightness shift. Gamma just turn the image white or dark, brightness makes the color too saturated

Answer (score 0):

It's a color space, h.264 are using YUV color while AVI RAW are using sRGB, you can convert BT601 to BT709  with ffmpeg CLI by using `-vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709`, but render with AVI JPEG format works too